# Functions and pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am trying to assign the return value of a function to variable, the problem is that this return value is an array, I understand that it will return a pointer, but as you can see below I just couldn't do the proper assignment, I've looked at many questions and don't seem to get what I need. So here is my function:

```
int randn(int n, int l){
    int r[n];
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<n; i++){
        r[i]=rand() % l;
        r[i]++;
        }
    return *r;
}
```

I believe the function is ok, but when I try to do this `int *o; o=randn(n,l);` I get this warning:

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled
>   by default]

And when I execute it, I get a segmentation fault.
This may be a dumb question, but I have been trying to solve this for a long time now. I would appreciate some kind help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `int randn(int n, int l)` does not return a pointer, it returns an int -- that's what its header says. `return *r` returns whatever type `*r` is, and since `r` is an array of ints, it points to ints and thus returns an int.

Comment: I understand that, what I don't know is how can I use the the resultant array, or how can I assing that array to a variable, which is what I need.

Comment: @mah: More correctly, since `r` is an array, it's implicitly converted to a pointer to the array object's first element.

Comment: to start with, never return an array that is defined as a local variable.  When that function exits, that variable 'goes out of scope'  I.E. becomes undefined garbage.   What could be done is to malloc the array, keep a pointer to that malloc'd array as a local variable, and return that pointer.  Of course, when done with that malloc'd array, pass it to free()

Comment: disregarding the above mentioned problem, this line: 'return *r;' does not return a pointer, it returns the first entry in 'r[]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct way to a pointer from a function. Also `r` is *local variable* whose lifetime is limited to the function. Allocate memory using [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and return it instead:

```
int* randn(int n, int l){
    int *r=malloc(n * sizeof *r);
    if(!r) { */ error */}
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<n; i++){
        r[i]=rand() % l;
        r[i]++;
        }
    return r;
}
```

Notice that I changed the signature as well to return a pointer (`int*`). Caller is responsible for `free()`ing the memory.

Comment: It does not seem to work :(. I am now getting another warning. 'warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]'

Comment: It works, I missed an *, thank you very much, and sorry for any trouble caused.

Comment: this line: 'int *r=malloc(n * sizeof *r);' is allocating an array of pointers to int.  however, those pointers are not being set to point to anything in particular.  perhaps you meant ''int *r=malloc(n * sizeof(int));'

Comment: @user3629249 so you say that sizeof(int) is not the same with sizeof(*r) in this particular example?

Answer (score 0):

1. What you return is actually the `r[0]` value.
2. Your `r` array disappears as soon as your function returns, and the pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: His code, as written, doesn't return a pointer. `return *r` is equivalent to `return r[0];`, and is quite safe; it returns an `int` value, not a pointer to a local object. Of course he *wants* to return the array, or a pointer to it, and that can't be done safely without taking some care with how the array is allocated.

Comment: @KeithThompson In fact, my second point speaks about OP's dangerous intentions rather than the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In C language it is not possible to return an array from a function. The proper way to go about it in C is to actually pass the recipient array from the calling code and then simply fill it inside the function

```
void randn(int n, int r[n], int l) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        r[i] = rand() % l;
        ++r[i];
    }
}

...
int o[n];
randn(n, o, l);
```

The approach with `malloc`-ing the array inside the function, while formally correct, is seriously flawed since it forces the code to work with dynamic memory. In many/most cases there's simply no reason to involve dynamic memory.

With this approach you have full freedom to put your array in any kind of memory you see fit, since the responsibility of providing that memory is imposed on the calling code.

Answer (score -1):

First, If you define an Array in C, say int r[n] in your case, the r is <strike>actually a const pointer</strike> in most of the context implicitly converted into a const pointer of first element. Although pointer and array is [different](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) pointer arithmetic and array indexing [that] are equivalent in C. The operator * get the value at pointer. So *r is equivalent to r[0] in this case. So you must return r not *r if you want to get the full array not the first element.

C compiler shows the warning because it checks that type of left hand side (int pointer) is not equal to type of right hand side (int).

```
int *o;
o = randn(n,l);
```

Second, a local variable exists in the memory as long as it is in the scope. C uses [Lexical Scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) (Static Scoping). As as soon as you are out of the function after return the memory of r will be freed. In C you will get Segmentation fault generally when you try to access a memory location not reserved by the Program.

So you need to allocate memory by using malloc. return type of malloc is (void *). So cast it into (int *).

```
int *r = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

malloc will not assign memory if it get no free memory at all. So its a good practice to check whether r is not NULL.

Change the return type of the function into (int *) from int. Remember C compiler only does this type checking by function declaration. It is not dependent on the actual returned value.

Memory allocated by malloc should be freed once the use is over by free(p) to avoid memory leak.

Comment: "First, If you define an Array in C, say int r[n] in your case, the r is actually an const pointer." Incorrect. Arrays are not pointers. An array expression is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's initial element. Read section of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Thank you a lot for the very interesting reference link. I will rewrite my answer after I read. Meanwhile I am changing my statement into "In this context". Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you read the CLC FAQ, you'll find that casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary and can be harmful in some cases. The result is implicitly converted from `void*` to the target pointer type. `int *r = malloc(n * sizeof *r);` is the recommended idiom.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you please provide some more in-depth references like this on C and Cpp that I should refer?

Comment: (It's called C++, not Cpp; the abbreviation cpp is often used to refer to the C preprocessor, and it's used in file names and URLS where "+" can cause problems.)  http://cppreference.com is pretty good for C++. There's also a list of references in section 18 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), though it's probably a bit out of date. The most definitive reference is the language standard.